# Elastic search class_cast_exception on PUT command

Tags: elasticsearch

**The command I am executing. It is for creating a new customer. Please see below for how i am creating Customer with PUT command on Sense (http://localhost:9200)**

```
 PUT /crud_sample/Customer_Info/1
        {
          "name": "PH"
        }
```

**The error I get:**

```
{
       "error": {
          "root_cause": [
             {
                "type": "class_cast_exception",
                "reason": "java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Number"
             }
          ],
          "type": "class_cast_exception",
          "reason": "java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Number"
       },
       "status": 500
    }
```

**The properties and type of object being created. The customer type.**

```
 "properties": { 
            "_id":{
             "type": "long"
            },
            "name":{
              "type": "string",
              "index" : "not_analyzed"
            }
          }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from the fact that you're defining a field called `_id` with an initial underscore in your mapping and ES won't allow it because it clashes with the default field called `_id` ([more info](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/9059)). You either need to remove that field or rename it to `id`.

You need to wipe your index and re-create it with a clean mapping, like this:

```
curl -XDELETE localhost:9200/crud_sample

curl -XPUT localhost:9200/crud_sample -d '{
    "mappings": {
        "Customer_Info": {
           "properties": { 
              "id":{
                 "type": "long"
              },
              "name":{
                 "type": "string",
                 "index" : "not_analyzed"
              }
           }
        }
    }
}'
```

Then you'll be able to create your sample document without error:

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/crud_sample/Customer_Info/1 -d '{
    "name": "PH"
}'
```